# permission denied for root user in mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have accidentally did some thing in MySQL database and broke MySQL.

```
:~# mysql -u root  
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)  
:~# mysql -u root -p  
Enter password:   
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

tried all the possible solution but still couldn't able to login to MySQL.
I have tried reinstall the package still same error.

Comment: you forgot `root` password? did you tried `mysql_secure_installation` ?

Comment: Thanks @arvind . after mysql_secure_installation it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you haven't configured mysql completely, try:

```
mysql_secure_installation
```